How do I ask gnu parallel to preserve stdin?
I'm using GNU parallel like this (:::: is a form of --arg-file):
parallel -0Xuj1 my-command -- :::: <(find … -print0)

But it seems like the command's standard input is managed by GNU parallel, which doesn't work for an interactive command.  The command complains when its stdin gets closed.  I'm guessing GNU parallel wants to use stdin to append to the arg list.
I've been able to use the command interactively with parallel's --tmux flag and reattaching, but that's needlessly complicated.
So far my workaround is to use plain xargs.  I'm not using find -exec my-command -- {} + because it builds an argument list that's too large for my-command (it's Python, it reexecs itself and breaks; parallel and xargs have a flag to leave some headroom).  Does anyone know a flag to tell GNU parallel to leave stdin alone?
xargs -0a <(find … -print0) my-command --


Can you explain a bit more? What's the point of running the command with parallel if you need to interact with each instance of command? Does find … -print0 | parallel -0Xuj1 my-command -- help?

It is a bit unclear to me what you are trying to do.
But your word interactively makes me think you are looking for --tty:
find . -type f | parallel --tty emacs

(or if you are a 6'er:
find . -type f | parallel --tty vi

)

What''s a 6'er?

@ilkkachu One who uses the roman numeral 6 (vi).

aargh! ‍♂️‍♂️
